How to OrderBy entity results using Map value included in the @Entity as @CollectionTable
I am trying to orderby value of a Map that is included in my @Entity as @CollectionTable @ElementCollection. I try to do this using criteriabuilder and eclipselink.
I provide below the entity example
@Entity
public class Voucher {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long voucherid;

    // other fields

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "voucherattribute", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "voucherid"))
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "voucherattributecode")
    @Column(name = "voucherattributevalue")
    private Map<String, String> voucherAttributes = new HashMap<>();

    // getters and setters
}


Below you can find the criteria builder example.
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Voucher> cq = cb.createQuery(Voucher.class);
Root<Voucher> voucher = cq.from(Voucher.class);
Join<Voucher, Map.Entry<String, String>> attributes = voucher.join("voucherAttributes");

cq.orderBy(cb.desc(attributes.value()));

TypedQuery<Voucher> query = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
List<Voucher> results = query.getResultList();


and the JPQL query to make it more understandble
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(
    "SELECT v.* FROM voucher v " +
    "JOIN voucherattribute va ON v.voucherid = va.voucherid " +
    "ORDER BY va.voucherattributevalue DESC", 
    Voucher.class
);
List<Voucher> results = query.getResultList();


I get below error when running the above criteria query
Exception Description: Query failed to prepare, unexpected error occurred: [java.lang.NullPointerException].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=EntityTableName )
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.prepareFailed(QueryException.java:1598)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.checkPrepare(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:968)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:881)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1191)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1279)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3004)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1898)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1880)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1845)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:482)
    ... 288 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.SQLSelectStatement.fieldsContainField(SQLSelectStatement.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.SQLSelectStatement.addOrderByExpressionToSelectForDistinct(SQLSelectStatement.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.SQLSelectStatement.normalize(SQLSelectStatement.java:1645)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.buildReportQuerySelectStatement(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:649)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.buildReportQuerySelectStatement(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.prepareReportQuerySelectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:1697)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReportQuery.prepareSelectAllRows(ReportQuery.java:1249)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.prepare(ReadAllQuery.java:841)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReportQuery.prepare(ReportQuery.java:1117)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:675)

Thank you!
I tried to use this annotation @OrderBy("AttributeValue DESC") but still the same issue.I tried to convert it to en Entity and it worked. Maybe the issue is related because is a hashmap?

Your criteria builder code is incomplete, making it impossible to tell what your query is selecting or really doing. Maybe simplify it to a JPQL query for the purpose of the question -you can verify in code operates the same as your criteria query and gets the same results. OrderBy on a map though doesn't make sense as maps are keyed collections with no ordering, and your query itself seems likely on the parent entity, not the values in the collection

Hello @Chris, I edited the description above to make it more clear. Yes I do select the parent entity, this is what I want to achieve, to order parent entity with the value in the collection table. Maybe the issue is because its a map. Just to notice that this works using JPQL but not criteria builder.
